# Installing WinPcap on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, winpcap

Is there a way to install WinPcap on Windows 8?

Windows refuses the install due to compatibility issues. Tried to set the compatibility mode to "Windows 7" and run as administrator but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved in [release 4.1.3](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/changelog.htm#changelog_4_1_3) of WinPcap - Added support for Windows 8 and Server 2012